# Replace textView for NumberPicker - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-number-picker

So I have some `textViews` that their inputs are numbers, but in order to be less prone to error I want to replace it with `numberPickers`.

**What I have done**

- `TextViews` work
- `NumberPickers` Work
- Any math and calculation works

**What I need**:

- To replace the input method
- This is what I have for my `textViews`

  ```
  when {

          time.text.isEmpty() && (distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
              calculatePace(null, distance.text.toString().toDouble(), pace.text.toString())

          distance.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
              calculatePace(time.text.toString(), null, pace.text.toString())

          pace.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && distance.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
              calculatePace(time.text.toString(), distance.text.toString().toDouble(), null)


          else -> {
              Toast.makeText(this, "Please check fields",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
          }
      }
  ```

These are my `pickers`:

```
    val pickerMinutes = numberPicker as NumberPicker
    val pickerSeconds = numberPickerSeconds as NumberPicker
    pickerMinutes.minValue = 0
    pickerMinutes.maxValue = 60
    pickerMinutes.wrapSelectorWheel = false
    pickerMinutes.isEnabled = true

    pickerSeconds.minValue = 0
    pickerSeconds.maxValue = 60
    pickerSeconds.wrapSelectorWheel = false
    pickerSeconds.isEnabled = true
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Not quite clear what is it you want ? as far I have been realised , do you want the input field as a number picker not TextView and need same calculation , is that it ? @Joedk

Comment: Hi Sorry, I already have the calculations (function) done. But at the moment the inputs are textViews and I want to replace them for number pickers :)

Comment: If you need your input to be only numbers, you can set the EditText inputType property to "number". "android:inputType="number"

Comment: I know that, but I need to user numberPicker (because of the reason I mentioned on my question), in order to avoid user input error since this involves time, so I always need the : separator

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) API , you will see there is a method `getValue()` which returns selected value , which is int return type . you can use `toDouble()` as your calculation method is taking double type

N.B as NumberPicker always works with integer I think you can modify your calculation method , as it will never get Double from NumberPicker

please confirm , if I didn't get what you want

Comment: this give me error  pickerMinutes.value && (distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->    I tried it before. Should I show you perhaps the whole class? (I am using Kotlin, thats why I am using .value and not getValue

Comment: this would help ,  give me your class with a https://pastebin.com/ link. this will help me dig deep

Comment: Going to do it. :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MpfRyrwq  ask me any questions. Right now what I have is passing the values from the pickers to the textviews, but thats not optimal. I want the inputs to be only from my pickers Thanks

Comment: I start solving this error , just need know which error you get after using pickerMinutes and pickerSeconds

Comment: I don't have any error in the code I sent you. But if I replace time.text.isEmpty() for pickerMinutes.value I get type mismatch required Boolean

Comment: Do you have any question @Vutka Bilai ?

Comment: Look here why you are getting type mismatch error , you are looking for isEmpty() method which is part of Textview class . If you use NumberPicker you don't need this validation . as you set  pickerMinutes.minValue = 0 . so by default it will be set to 0 .(distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
                calculatePace(null, distance.text.toString().toDouble(), pace.text.toString()) remove time.text.isEmpty()

Comment: I did not use .isEmpty on my numberPicker. Look what I used :P The thing is I don't want to use my text Views anymore. I know how to pass my Number Picker values to the text views. What I want to do is replace the text views for my number pickers.

Comment: I get it :p ; i know what you did 
pickerMinutes.value && (distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
                    calculatePace(null, distance.text.toString().toDouble(), pace.text.toString())

what does pickerMinutes.value retruns ?? it returns int , so how "&&" operators works on boolean and int . it is not possible . 

so when you need number picker value for calculation use pickerMinutes.value . you don't need to validate is it empty or not

Comment: So I just do  pickerMinutes.value.(distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) -> calculatePace(null, distance.text.toString().toDouble(), pace.text.toString())  ?

Comment: error as well. I think I am missing something basic here :/

Comment: Any ideas @Vutka? :)